# Why the output of this program is 41? is it undefined behavior?

Tags: c, output, undefined-behavior

```
    #include<Stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
     int j=5;
     j=++j + ++j + ++j + ++j + ++j;
     printf("%d",j);
    }
```

when i am running this C program using codeblocks IDE(GCC compiler) it is showing the output as 41.I'm not getting why the output is 41.is it compiler specific?

Comment: Yes. [filler text to make comment 15 characters long]

Comment: Yes you have undefined behavior.

Comment: While [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) is in regards to C++, the rules regarding sequencing are basically the same in C.