# Macro in GCC and VC++

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc

I got this code compiled in VC++ and GCC that produces different outputs and appreciate if someone can point me out where the things get wrong.

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define Cube(x) x*x*x

int main(void){

    int x=5;
    printf("%d\r\n", Cube(x++));

return 0;
}
```

In GCC, the displayed value is 210 (=5*6*7) and in VC++2010 its 125 (=5*5*5).

If I do this,

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define Cube(x) x*x*x

int main(void){

    int x=5;
    printf("%d\r\n", Cube(++x));

return 0;
}
```

VC++ prints 512 (=8*8*8) and GCC prints 392 (=7*7*8).

Appreciate if someone can say whats going on.

Comment: Incorrect code *should* produce different results on different compilers. And it should also produce warnings if they're turned on. So turn on warnings, and change the code to something correct.

Comment: this is a case where (besides the undefined behaviour from the 'side effect'') it would be necessary to write the 'x*x*x' as '(x)*(x)*(x)' to avoid certain 'text replacement' problems.   In general, do not incorporate 'side effects' into the parameters for a macro.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I do understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
printf("%d\r\n", Cube(x++));
```

is pre-processed to:

```
printf("%d\r\n", x++*x++*x++));
```

That is cause for undefined behavior.

```
printf("%d\r\n", ++x*++x*++x));
```

is also cause for undefined behavior.

See
[Why the output of this program is 41? is it undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622108/why-the-output-of-this-program-is-41-is-it-undefined-behavior)
[Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)

You can avoid the problem by converting `Cube` to a function. The program below is well behaved.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int Cube(int x)
{
   return x*x*x;
}

int main(void)
{
   int x=5;
   printf("%d\r\n", Cube(x++));
   printf("%d\r\n", Cube(++x));

   return 0;
}
```